# Spider Species Identification

Tags: species-identification

Can anyone identify this species of spider and whether or not is is venomous?[image]
Location: South Carolina, USA.

Comment: Hi Jody.. based on your profile, I added your location to be SC, USA. If this is incorrect, please edit.

Comment: Also the size and the habitat might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a *[Nephila clavipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephila_clavipes#cite_note-3)*, a.k.a, "golden silk spider". According to Wiki, this is the only [golden web-orb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_silk_orb-weaver) species that's indigenous to America.

[image]

> Can anyone identify this species of spider and **whether or not it is venomous?**

*"..there is little real danger from an encounter with the golden silk spider. The spider will bite only if held or pinched, and the bite itself will produce only localized pain with a slight redness, which quickly goes away. **On the whole, the bite is much less severe than a bee string.**"* ([source](http://entomology.ifas.ufl.edu/creatures/misc/golden_silk_spider.htm))